# How to convert Doctrine2 entity graph to array

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities

- [Product Entity](http://pastebin.com/atNNRxWw)
- [Category Entity](http://pastebin.com/QGU7A0vr)
- [Tag Entity](http://pastebin.com/VmzxMBd2)
- [Brand Entity](http://pastebin.com/mfb83LsK)

What I am trying to do is when I get the Product by id, I want to convert it to array including all associated entities including their associated entries.

The result array needs to be serializable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use doctrine query builder and the HYDRATE_ARRAY hydration mode?

Edit: Sorry for not including examples, I was on my mobile at the time. Check out [the blog post](http://blog.ultravioletdesign.co.uk/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/) I wrote on some good practices with doctrine that semi-relates to this.

For a code example the repository method I would write to cover this would be as follows (I would avoid using abbreviations like `p` `c` etc. as it makes your code a lot less readable (at least while you are getting started with doctrine...)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Prefix\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        // $em is the entity manager
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb
            ->select('product', 'category', 'tag', 'brand', 'category_child')
            // Or SomeBundle:Product if you're on symfony
            ->from('Vendor\Prefix\Entity\Product', 'product')
            // You need to explicitly fetch join all your 
            // associations...and select them
            ->leftJoin('product.Brand', 'brand')
            ->leftJoin('product.Tags', 'tag')
            ->leftJoin('product.Categories', 'category')
            ->leftJoin('category.Children', 'category_child')
            // Use prepared statments...its a good habit
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('product.ID', ':id'))
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ;

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        // Potential Hydration Modes
        // --------------------------------
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY 
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT

        // Hydrate the result as an array to get the requested format
        // When you use array hyrdation doctrine does it according 
        // to your entity graph
        return $query->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite new to doctrine2. Could you give me some code example?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's a good idea not using abbreviations. If you check my comment to @S0pra, I managed to get this working. Event getting the Product's categories parent category, but for some reason I can't get the children categories of the product category (pheww..)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JOIN in DQL syntax:

```
$results = $entityManager->executeQuery('SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN p.Brand b JOIN p.Tags t JOIN p.Categories c')->getArrayResult();
var_dump($results);
```

Also, I think you should avoid class members starting with an uppercase letter. It could introduce a bit of confusion with the entity name.

Comment: That's great. I amended it like this `        $dql = 'SELECT
                    p, b, c, t, cp
                FROM
                    \App\Domain\Entity\Product p
                    LEFT JOIN p.Brand b
                    LEFT JOIN p.Categories c
                    LEFT JOIN c.Parent cp
                    LEFT JOIN p.Tags t
                WHERE
                    p.ID = ?1';`
now it retrieves the parent of the product's category as well. Only bit missing is the children of the product's category. If I add `LEFT JOIN c.Children cc`, the result returns empty array